# Problem with Celery automation in aws EBS and during autoscaling

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-celery

When the new instance is created, celery is not running in that new instance and while deploying the project to EBS celery is not starting automatically by the supervisord. The "supervisord.conf" file to run the celery in the background:

```
    ; Sample supervisor config file.
    ;
    ; For more information on the config file, please see:
    ; http://supervisord.org/configuration.html
    ;
    ; Warning:
    ;  Paths throughout this example file use /tmp because it is available on most
    ;  systems.  You will likely need to change these to locations more appropriate
    ;  for your system.  Some systems periodically delete older files in /tmp.
    ;  Notably, if the socket file defined in the [unix_http_server] section below
    ;  is deleted, supervisorctl will be unable to connect to supervisord.
    
    [unix_http_server]
    file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; the path to the socket file
    ;chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
    ;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner
    ;username=user              ; default is no username (open server)
    ;password=123               ; default is no password (open server)
    
    ; Security Warning:
    ;  The inet HTTP server is not enabled by default.  The inet HTTP server is
    ;  enabled by uncommenting the [inet_http_server] section below.  The inet
    ;  HTTP server is intended for use within a trusted environment only.  It
    ;  should only be bound to localhost or only accessible from within an
    ;  isolated, trusted network.  The inet HTTP server does not support any
    ;  form of encryption.  The inet HTTP server does not use authentication
    ;  by default (see the username= and password= options to add authentication).
    ;  Never expose the inet HTTP server to the public internet.
    
    ;[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
    ;port=127.0.0.1:9001        ; ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface
    ;username=user              ; default is no username (open server)
    ;password=123               ; default is no password (open server)
    
    [supervisord]
    logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
    logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
    logfile_backups=10           ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
    loglevel=info                ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
    pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; supervisord pidfile; default supervisord.pid
    nodaemon=false               ; start in foreground if true; default false
    silent=false                 ; no logs to stdout if true; default false
    minfds=1024                  ; min. avail startup file descriptors; default 1024
    minprocs=200                 ; min. avail process descriptors;default 200
    ;umask=022                   ; process file creation umask; default 022
    ;user=supervisord            ; setuid to this UNIX account at startup; recommended if root
    ;identifier=supervisor       ; supervisord identifier, default is 'supervisor'
    ;directory=/tmp              ; default is not to cd during start
    ;nocleanup=true              ; don't clean up tempfiles at start; default false
    ;childlogdir=/tmp            ; 'AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP
    ;environment=KEY="value"     ; key value pairs to add to environment
    ;strip_ansi=false            ; strip ansi escape codes in logs; def. false
    
    ; The rpcinterface:supervisor section must remain in the config file for
    ; RPC (supervisorctl/web interface) to work.  Additional interfaces may be
    ; added by defining them in separate [rpcinterface:x] sections.
    
    [rpcinterface:supervisor]
    supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
    
    ; The supervisorctl section configures how supervisorctl will connect to
    ; supervisord.  configure it match the settings in either the unix_http_server
    ; or inet_http_server section.
    
    [program:celeryd]
    command=/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/celery -A main worker --loglevel=info
    stdout_logfile=/tmp/celeryd.log
    stderr_logfile=/tmp/celeryd.log
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    startsecs=10
    stopwaitsecs=600
    
    [program:celerybeat]
    command=/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/celery beat -A main --pidfile="/tmp/celerybeat.pid"
    stdout_logfile=/tmp/celerybeat.log
    stderr_logfile=/tmp/celerybeat.log
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    startsecs=10
    stopwaitsecs=600
    
    [supervisorctl]
    serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
    ;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
    ;username=chris              ; should be same as in [*_http_server] if set
    ;password=123                ; should be same as in [*_http_server] if set
    ;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")
    ;history_file=~/.sc_history  ; use readline history if available
    
    ; The sample program section below shows all possible program subsection values.
    ; Create one or more 'real' program: sections to be able to control them under
    ; supervisor.
    
    ;[program:theprogramname]
    ;command=/bin/cat              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
    ;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
    ;numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
    ;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
    ;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
    ;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
    ;autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
    ;startsecs=1                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
    ;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
    ;autorestart=unexpected        ; when to restart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
    ;exitcodes=0                   ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0)
    ;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
    ;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
    ;stopasgroup=false             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
    ;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
    ;user=chrism                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
    ;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
    ;stdout_logfile=/a/path        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
    ;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
    ;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
    ;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
    ;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
    ;stdout_syslog=false           ; send stdout to syslog with process name (default false)
    ;stderr_logfile=/a/path        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
    ;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
    ;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
    ;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
    ;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
    ;stderr_syslog=false           ; send stderr to syslog with process name (default false)
    ;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
    ;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)
    
    ; The sample eventlistener section below shows all possible eventlistener
    ; subsection values.  Create one or more 'real' eventlistener: sections to be
    ; able to handle event notifications sent by supervisord.
    
    ;[eventlistener:theeventlistenername]
    ;command=/bin/eventlistener    ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
    ;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
    ;numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
    ;events=EVENT                  ; event notif. types to subscribe to (req'd)
    ;buffer_size=10                ; event buffer queue size (default 10)
    ;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
    ;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
    ;priority=-1                   ; the relative start priority (default -1)
    ;autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
    ;startsecs=1                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
    ;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
    ;autorestart=unexpected        ; autorestart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
    ;exitcodes=0                   ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0)
    ;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
    ;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
    ;stopasgroup=false             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
    ;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
    ;user=chrism                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
    ;redirect_stderr=false         ; redirect_stderr=true is not allowed for eventlisteners
    ;stdout_logfile=/a/path        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
    ;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
    ;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
    ;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
    ;stdout_syslog=false           ; send stdout to syslog with process name (default false)
    ;stderr_logfile=/a/path        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
    ;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
    ;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
    ;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
    ;stderr_syslog=false           ; send stderr to syslog with process name (default false)
    ;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions
    ;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)
    
    ; The sample group section below shows all possible group values.  Create one
    ; or more 'real' group: sections to create "heterogeneous" process groups.
    
    ;[group:thegroupname]
    ;programs=progname1,progname2  ; each refers to 'x' in [program:x] definitions
    ;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
    
    ; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
    ; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
    ; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
    ; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
    ; include files themselves.
    
    ;[include]
    ;files = relative/directory/*.ini
```

".ebextension/build.config" this file has the command that was suppose to run supervisord after the deployment is done

```
container_commands:
 command1:
  command: "test -f /usr/bin/google-chrome || wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm"
 command2:
  command: "test -f /usr/bin/google-chrome || sudo yum -y install ./google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm"
 command3:
  command: "sudo cp -r /home/ec2-user/nltk_data /usr/share/nltk_data"
 command4:
  command: "test -f /usr/bin/supervisord || sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y epel"
 command5:
  command: "test -f /usr/bin/supervisord || sudo yum install -y supervisor"
 command6:
  command: "sudo unlink /tmp/supervisor.sock"
 command7:
  command: "sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/app/current"
 command8:
  command: "/usr/bin/supervisord -c /var/app/current/supervisord.conf"
  cwd: "/var/app/current"
```

The project gets deployed successfully but success rate is not consistent.

Need to figure out how i make celery to run automatically after i do  "eb deploy" of my project to aws and when the scaling of my instance is triggered the celery should run automatically in that new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those guys who are also stuck in this same situation. I scrapped the idea of using supervisord and instead i created a "Procfile" in the root directory and added "celery worker" command of celery(where i use the absolute path for celery to my venv location).Both for worker and beat then when i deployed it, "systemd" will take care of running celery in the background hence solving the problem of running my celery after i deploy it. No problem so far and my website been running good. Make sure to include the log file in the celery command.

Comment: Won't this lead to duplicate task execution when you have multiple instances?

Comment: i should edit this then.....i include only the celery worker command in the  "Procfile" not the celery beat.